# Looping through all file stored in a azure blob storage in R

Tags: r, azure-storage

I would appreciate your help please.

I have some .parquet files in a azure blob storage container.

I am able to individual read in just one file at a time using R

The code is:

```
raw_data <- download_from_url("https://myacct.blob.core.windows.net/retail.parquet",
                  key="wRGSJ", dest=NULL)
parq_df <- read_parquet(raw_data)
```

Instead I want to write a loop that go through, read in the files and append all of the files in the container and append them as one parquet file.

I am stuck at the moment, i would appreciate any help i can get. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read and combine multiple parquet files from an Azure Blob Storage container

1. **List all the files in the blob container**:
   You'll first need a list of all parquet files in the container.
2. **Loop through the list and download and read each file**:
   This will be done in a loop, and for each file, you'll append the data to a main dataframe.
3. **Write the combined dataframe to a new parquet file**.

Sample Code:

```
library(arrow)

# Function to list all files in the blob container
list_blobs <- function(container_url, key) {
  # Using AzureStor package
  library(AzureStor)
  
  blob_endpoint <- paste0("https://", container_url, "/")
  blob_account <- storage_endpoint(blob_endpoint, key=key)
  blob_container <- storage_container(blob_account, "your-container-name")
  
  # List the blob names
  blob_list <- list_blobs(blob_container)
  
  return(blob_list)
}

# List all the parquet files
all_files <- list_blobs("myacct.blob.core.windows.net", "wRGSJ")
all_data <- list()

# Loop through each file, download, and read
for(file_url in all_files) {
  raw_data <- download_from_url(file_url, key="wRGSJ", dest=NULL)
  parq_df <- read_parquet(raw_data)
  
  # Append the data
  all_data[[length(all_data) + 1]] <- parq_df
}

# Combine all data
combined_data <- do.call(rbind, all_data)

# Write to a single parquet file
write_parquet(combined_data, "combined.parquet")
```

- The function `list_blobs` uses the `AzureStor` package to list all files in the blob container.